# redirect nor working -> overwriting all the time

Tags: redirect

I did a redirect as I saw this http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-adding-page-links-in-the-navigation-bar.html

It worked fine, until we added new products. Now the redirect is not here anymore as I defined, it is the "old" redirect here instead.

How I can prevent this overwriting?

Comment: Did you clear the cache?

Comment: Yes, it will work - as I figured out, until we upload new products. I tried to do more than one time.
It likes "fall" back to the first "settings".

Comment: Did you clear the cache after adding products?

Comment: Yes, we do this too. All the times.